# How to use tinymce plugin in other plugins in Croogo 1.3?

Tags: php, cakephp

In

> tinymce_bootstrap.php

I tried:

```
'gallery/photos/admin_edit_photo' => array(
        array(
            'elements' => 'PhotoDescription',
        ),
    ),
```

`Gallery` is my plugin

but it doesn't work. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it the easy-way:

> var $helpers = array('Tinymce.Tinymce');

in my plugins's

> controller

but there must be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a PhotosController (either in a plugin or main app) with admin_edit_photo() action, and your Photo model has a 'description' field, add this to the bootstrap:

```
 'Photos/admin_edit_photo' => array(
     array(
         'elements' => 'PhotoDescription',
     ),
 ),
```

See the Tinymce plugin's bootstrap for reference: https://github.com/croogo/croogo/blob/1.3/plugins/tinymce/config/tinymce_bootstrap.php